# compile time parameter checking

Tags: c++, templates, qt5

I'm trying to understand how the Qt5 framework's Signals and Slots mechanism does type checking on function arguments.

I've provided a summary of the section of code I'm interested in. The only thing I'm having trouble understanding is the following template specialization. How does the compiler decide to instantiate this? I especially don't understand when template parameter list `template< typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename... Tail1, typename... Tail2 >` is considered.

```
template< typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename... Tail1, typename... Tail2 >
  struct Test< List< Arg1, Tail1... >, List< Arg2, Tail2... > > {
    enum { value = ArgsCompat< Arg1, Arg2 >::value && Test< List< Tail1... >, List< Tail2... > >::value };
  };
```

````
namespace Test {
  template< typename... >
  struct List{};

  template< typename H, typename... T >
  struct List< H, T... >{
    typedef H Head;
    typedef List< T... > Tail;
  };

  template< typename T > struct RemoveRef { typedef T type; };
  template< typename T > struct RemoveRef< T& > { typedef T type; };

  template< typename Arg1, typename Arg2 >
  struct ArgsCompat {
    static int test( const typename RemoveRef< Arg2 >::type & );
    enum { value = true };
  };

  template< typename Elem1, typename Elem2 > struct Test { enum { value = false}; };
  template<> struct Test< List<>, List<> > { enum { value = true }; };
  template< typename Arg1> struct Test< Arg1, List<> > { enum { value = true }; };
  template< typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename... Tail1, typename... Tail2 >
  struct Test< List< Arg1, Tail1... >, List< Arg2, Tail2... > > {
    enum { value = ArgsCompat< Arg1, Arg2 >::value && Test< List< Tail1... >, List< Tail2... > >::value };
  };

}

int main( void ) {
  static_assert( Test::Test< Test::List<>, Test::List<> >::value, "" );
  static_assert( Test::Test< Test::List< char >, Test::List< char > >::value, "" );
  static_assert( Test::Test< Test::List< char, int, double >, Test::List< char, int, double > >::value, "expected true" );
  return 0;
}```
````

Comment: It's just a standard recursive definition. "Two lists are compatible if the corresponding first items are compatible, and the remainder of the items are compatible (calculated recursively)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to the instantiations in the two last `static_assert`s, they both match these:

```
template <typename Elem1, typename Elem2> struct Test { enum { value = false }; };
```

```
template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename... Tail1, typename... Tail2>
struct Test<List<Arg1, Tail1...>, List<Arg2, Tail2...> > { ... };
```

When there's more than one template matching, it always selects the one that is more constrained, which is the second one in this case. The first one is more relaxed (`Elem1` and `Elem2` can be *anything*). If they had been equally constrained there would have been ambiguity and compilation would fail.

The parameters in the first `static_assert` matches these two:

```
template <typename Elem1, typename Elem2> struct Test { enum { value = false }; };
```

```
template <> struct Test<List<>, List<> > { enum { value = true }; };
```

and again, the second one is more constrained and is therefore selected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ted. The 2 last static asserts are the ones I'm trying to understand. What I don't get is how Arg1 and Tail1 are formed. What rule tells the compiler that for instance 'char' should be Arg1 and 'int, double' should be Tail1.

Comment: NVM, I think I get it now. The compiler is selecting the Test< List< Arg1, Tail1... >, List< Arg2, Tail2... > >`` part because its the more specialized one, as pointed out by Ted. The `template <typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename... Tail1, typename... Tail2>` just declares the template types that are being used as part of the specialization.

Comment: @stackr Sorry for missing your first comment. Yes, it sounds like you got it and _"more specialized"_ is probably a better description than _"more constrained_" that I used.